# View not showing full results when data has already been loaded

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to combine one of my template(test.blade.php) to a new view page which contain a button where it will show a pop up form when clicked. But for some reason when I do that nothing only a few information taken from test.blade.php. Even the button is missing but if I were to place the include('test') at another location, it will show the button but even lesser information being shown.

Here is the code:

evaltest.blade.php (div_show this will display the form)

```
  <html>
    <head> 
        <title>Popup form </title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">    
        <link href="{{ asset('css/elements.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-43981329-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
    </head> 
     <!-- body starts here -->
     <body id ="bdy" style="overflow:hidden;">

     <div id="abc">

         <!-- Popup div starts here -->
     <div id="popupContact"> 

        <!-- contact us form -->
             <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/evaltest/'.$data0->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <img id ="close" src="{{ URL::to('/image') }}/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
             <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data0->id}}">

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Recommendation:</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="No"> No<br>
          </div>
      </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
                  <input id= "submit" type="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
     </div> 
    <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
    </div>
    <!-- Display Popup Button -->
//this will show a few info but no button       
@include('test')
    <h1>Click Button to Evaluate</h1>
    <button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/my_js.js') }}"></script>
//this will show even lesser info but button is shown
//@include('test')
    </body>
    </html>
```

test.blade.php (there are more information inside but I only put some as an example of how I got the information)

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    <b>Alias: </b>{{ $object->Alias }}<br><br>
    <b>Email: </b>{{$object->Email}}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

This is the screenshot I am facing right now:
[image]

This is the screenshot of test.blade.php which I want it to be together with evaltest.blade.php
[image]

As you can see in the test.blade.php, there is a scroll bar which contain other kind of information and it also contain many other information but evaltest.blade.php only show a few but when I view page source for evaltest.blade.php, it shows that all the data have already been loaded

Comment: Please put **@include('test')** inside <div id="abc"> and try its work or not

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I have tried that before but that is not what I want, what I want is the @include('test') to be together with the button so that user can reference it in the background not when the user click the button to show the information, the button is to only show the form

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in your `elements.css` file. There's a style rule there fixing the height or something similar.

Comment: thanks for replying, I was just following this website to try and make the popup button, could you help me take a look at the css part and see which part that need to be taken out or maybe tell me which part I need to take note of? Here is the link, https://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/

Comment: The css that I used is the same as the elements.css in the link @Lloople